# What is the cause of "Trust anchor for certification path not found."

Tags: java, android, sql-server, android-studio, android-studio-2.3

This maybe a clone from this thread [Anchor not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825226/trust-anchor-not-found-for-android-ssl-connection) but apparently I can't make it run. I have a very limited knowledge in android studio and this is my first time to develop an application using android studio. Does anyone here can lead me to the right track to solve this problem? I have attached my logcat below.

[image]