# Android :Getting SSLHandshakeException. CertPathValidatorException when streaming audio using ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer, sslhandshakeexception, exoplayer2.x

I am getting an exception while streaming the audio from the network using **ExoPlayer**

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

How can i add the certificates to ExoPlayer or Android to resolve this.

Comment: You can refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825226/trust-anchor-not-found-for-android-ssl-connection

Comment: @Thientvse I am not making any service call, Internally ExoPlayer is making the call. So where could I add the certificates?