# On Android 8. +: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: android, ssl

android studio 3.2.1

on android 6.0 my project start success, but on Android 8.0+ 
I get error:

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:219)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:406)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.updateSecureConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:243)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.layerProtocol(AbstractPoolEntry.java:307)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.layerProtocol(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:151)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.establishRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:668)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:376)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:596)
```

if I set

```
android:targetSdkVersion="21"
```

this fix problem.
But in production I must use at least `android:targetSdkVersion="26"`

So how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trust Anchor not found for Android SSL Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825226/trust-anchor-not-found-for-android-ssl-connection)