# Glide load an image from an URl

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I'm trying to use Glide to load an image from an Url:

```
Glide.with(getContext()).load(urlImage).error(R.drawable.ic_profile_default).into(imgUser);
```

This is the error I get:

```
W/Glide: Load failed for https:www.cerberusenlinea.com/images/profile/16/13/HOLCIM.jpeg with size [204x204]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 cause:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException(java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to take the image from a not secure website, so glide blocks you.
To solve this issue you can create a custom trust manager but is very dangerous because you get exposed to man in the middle attack.
If you want to follow this route i suggest you to read this 
[Trust Anchor not found for Android SSL Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825226/trust-anchor-not-found-for-android-ssl-connection)

Another work around solution, that i suggest could be download the image and host it on 
 your server or on a free service (you can found a lot of them) like https://imgur.com/upload or everyone else

Answer (score 0):

The HTTPS configuration for the site www.cerberusenlinea.com has chain issues.

You can verify it in the Qualys Free Scanner: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.cerberusenlinea.com

[image: Result qualys scanner]

Android requires the full certificate chain in order to consume the content.

The [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl#MissingCa) says:

> Most public CAs don't sign server certificates directly. Instead, they
>   use their main CA certificate, referred to as the root CA, to sign
>   intermediate CAs. They do this so the root CA can be stored offline to
>   reduce risk of compromise. However, operating systems like Android
>   typically trust only root CAs directly, which leaves a short gap of
>   trust between the server certificate—signed by the intermediate CA—and
>   the certificate verifier, which knows the root CA. To solve this, the
>   server doesn't send the client only it's certificate during the SSL
>   handshake, but a chain of certificates from the server CA through any
>   intermediates necessary to reach a trusted root CA.

The documentation mention some alternatives in order to address the problem from the application side.