# Problem with certificate path in communication to server for second request

Tags: android, ssl, certificate, sslhandshakeexception

I have a problem between Android communication and the server using certificate. Using my native Android app, in first request to the server, it works okay.

After to remove it of multitaks and open it again, it happens the following error shown in logcat: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

I don't understand why this happens, 'cause in first request all works okay. Only in second request, after to remove it of multitask, this error is thrown.

Observation: native iOS app works okay and this error doesn't happens.

Comment: This post going to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825226/trust-anchor-not-found-for-android-ssl-connection

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trust Anchor not found for Android SSL Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825226/trust-anchor-not-found-for-android-ssl-connection)