# How to consume an API that use a self signed SSL?

Tags: api, c#-4.0, xamarin.android, ssl-certificate, self-signed

is there any one who can provide me with the way of consuming an API that use a self signed SSL in xamarin android.
An Exception thrown says:
`Javax.Net.Ssl.HandshakeException:`
`'java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found'.`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHw77.jpg)

Comment: If you need any more details concerning my code, let me know and i will provide you with it

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check whether SSL Certificate is correctly configured with the Certificate in your web.
We have to add the intermediate certificates in generating the .pem file.

You can go through this thread to install the intermediate certificate in your server:

[Trust Anchor not found for Android SSL Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825226/trust-anchor-not-found-for-android-ssl-connection/16302527#16302527)

And there is a similar thread about this, you can check it here:[Trust anchor for certification path not found [ Xamarin.Forms ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60636149/trust-anchor-for-certification-path-not-found-xamarin-forms) .