# Pre-installed PdfViewerActivity does not work with SelfSigned trusted user certificate Android 11 ver 2

Tags: android, ssl, self-signed, sslhandshakeexception, pdf-viewer

I have a server with SelfSigned certificate. This certificate has been added to the Trusted credentials/User list on the Android 11 device. My application and browser work correctly with it: I can download pdf file from MyServer througt Chrome browser.

My network-security-config.xml

```
<network-security-config xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors tools:ignore="AcceptsUserCertificates">
            <!-- Trust preinstalled CAs -->
            <certificates src="system" />
            <!-- Additionally trust user added CAs -->
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

But, when I try to open pdf file I got SSLHandshakeException from PdfViewerActivity.
My code:

```
Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.myserver.com/example.pdf"));
startActivity(pdfIntent);
```

Error log:

> I/ActivityTaskManager: Displayed com.google.android.apps.docs/com.google.android.apps.viewer.PdfViewerActivity: +163ms

> E/HttpUriOpener: general IOException: SSLHandshakeException

> E/PdfViewerActivity: fetchFile:https: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Is it bug inside PdfViewerActivity or I have done something wrong?
I will appreciate any idea how to fix this problem.

UPD: [Trust Anchor not found for Android SSL Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825226/trust-anchor-not-found-for-android-ssl-connection) is NOT the answer to my question. It does not contains information about work with SelfTrusted sertificate on Android 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it bug inside PdfViewerActivity or I have done something wrong?

Neither. There are dozens of possible PDF viewer apps that might be launched by that `Intent`. None of them are your app, and so none of them are affected by your network security configuration. And on newer versions of Android, user-installed certificates are ignored by default.

You will need to download the PDF file yourself, then use `FileProvider` and its `getUriForFile()` method to get a `Uri` to use with your `Intent`.

Alternatively, you could switch the server to use a regular SSL certificate (e.g., Let's Encrypt) instead of a self-signed certificate, if that is practical for your situation.