# recommend way of resolving Trust Anchor not found for Android SSL Connection

Tags: java, android, ssl

I am trying to create a keystore for my android app because I am guessing it doesn't trust the root ca for my Digi cert issued certificate. It's a real ssl certificate issued by Ionos but the root ca is digi cert.

I am using web sockets in my android app and I get this error enter

[image]

so I am trying to create a custom SSLSocketFactory that uses the built-in certificate KeyStore, but falls back on an alternate KeyStore for anything that fails to verify with the default.
After some research, I came across this stack overflow [Trust Anchor not found for Android SSL Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825226/trust-anchor-not-found-for-android-ssl-connection) which mensions bks keystore however according to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iB41HWOhVnc bks keystores arent considered secure anymore.

so what is the recommended method nowadays? I will require full instructions as I am absolutely clueless. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: There no code t show. I am asking for advise

Comment: What you can try is to use the default jdk trusted certificates, android ca trusted certificates and also include the ssl certificate issued by Ionos. These two links will give you examples how to load them all: https://github.com/Hakky54/sslcontext-kickstart#loading-jdk-and-os-trusted-certificates and https://github.com/Hakky54/sslcontext-kickstart#using-der-files By the way this is my library... Please let me know if this works for you. The SSLFactory instance will give you a SSLSocketFactory

Comment: Hi thanks for providing me with a library to do this. but how do I then connect the sslcontext to a websocket client

Comment: @Ageis which websocket are you using?

Comment: WebSocketClient the org.java_websocket.client https://javadoc.io/doc/org.java-websocket/Java-WebSocket/latest/index.html

Comment: You can just do: `webSocketClient.setSocketFactory(sslfactory.getSslSocketFacktory())` can you give it a try and share your results here?