# Tomcat - Getting Java SSLException hostname in certificate didn't match

Tags: java, ssl, https, tomcat8

On my machine (on a main method) I am able to consume an https web service using this code:

```
    URL url;
    HttpsURLConnection connection;

    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(
            new javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier(){
                public boolean verify(String hostname,
                        javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

    //prepare the request
    byte[] postData = xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    int postDataLength = postData.length;

    url = new URL(ENDPOINT_URL);//https endpoint

    connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataLength));

    DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    outputStream.write(postData);

    //make the request and get response xml string
    connection.getResponseCode();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    return response.toString();
```

Notice that on the code I bypass hostname verification, according to the answers to this post: [Java SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256955/java-sslexception-hostname-in-certificate-didnt-match)

But if I try to consume the exact same https web service, using the exact same code, on the the exact same machine (my local machine), but from a webapp deployed on Tomcat 8, I get the error:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found
```

I have searched for anwsers and solutions to this problem but found none. I am clueless. Do you have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Don't set the content length. Java does that for you automatically.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Any idea on why that error occurs on Tomcat?