# How to fix Hostname in certificate didn't match

Tags: java, ssl, unirest

I'm making HTTP request to a https website using Unirest for Java, but I have problem with SSL certificate. Exception message - javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match:

Page: www.ceskereality.cz

If I open it in browser (I'm using Google Chrome on Windows 10), it works...

I tried this, but it isn't working

```
SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
                .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                .build();

SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext,SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
                .build();
Unirest.setHttpClient(httpclient);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256955/java-sslexception-hostname-in-certificate-didnt-match)

Comment: Problem is that if I open that page in browser it works... (question edited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server requires that the client uses [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) in order to get the correct certificate. If no SNI is used a certificate for `ci.cz` instead of `ceskereality.cz` is returned which causes the error you see.

I'm not familiar with Unirest but it is likely that the library you use does not support SNI or that you are using it with an older Java version which does not have SNI enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Download the server cert and place it in your cacerts and restart your java application.