# Why HttpClient works directly in Linux server or Windows server but not works in tomcat server?

Tags: android, httpclient

When i execute same URL via HttpClient object then directly works in Linux Server or Windows Server but not works in tomcat Server.

My codes are given below :

```
try {
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "https://192.xxx.x.xx:8443/resources/login");
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("problem", "" + " ," + e.toString());

        }
```

When run this, then Exception Throw

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
```

How to solve this. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

SSLPeerUnverifiedException occures on `https://`. Using `http://` will remove that exception. But it is not a good practice. Probably you need the class `SSLSocketFactory`. Refer to [Android SSL - No Peer Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806128/android-ssl-no-peer-certificate)