# Android SSL trust chain with intermediate certificates (Apache HttpClient 4.X)

Tags: java, android, ssl, certificate, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to query a HTTPS website with Apache's HttpClient 4.X from an android app. I get an `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate` exception. I followed different instructions on importing the certificates:

- [How do I avoid getting "No peer certificate" error when connecting to this HTTPS site on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583548/how-do-i-avoid-getting-no-peer-certificate-error-when-connecting-to-this-https?rq=1)
- [Https Connection Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995514/https-connection-android#1000205)
- [HTTPS GET (SSL) with Android and self-signed server certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761737/https-get-ssl-with-android-and-self-signed-server-certificate/4008166#4008166)

None of these worked for me.

I think my problem is that the site's Certificate chain is as follows:

- Telekom Root CA 2

  - Intermediate A

    - Intermediate B

      - Site's certificate

The *Telekom Root CA 2* is included in the Android default keystore (`/system/etc/security/cacerts.bks`). I checked that on my own phone I use for testing.

Now the question is, which certificates do I have to include in the custom keystore all the instructions tell me to provide? Just the intermediates? Only the site? Both? Do I need the Root certificate as well? Shouldn't the `Site's certificate` be verified by the chain - I would not need to provide any extra certificates since the root of the chain is trusted.

I would be happy if you could explain to me what is going on and how I could get this to work. Please do not post workarounds which just ignore the Certificates, since this is intended for production and has to be secure.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a blog post, including a full working example a while back about how to do exactly this. See http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/https-with-client-certificates-on/

([Code from that blog post on GitHub](https://github.com/rfreedman/android-ssl))