# Specifying trust store information in spring boot application.properties

Tags: ssl, properties, spring-boot, truststore

I am using ***springBootVersion 1.2.0.RELEASE***.
I'm trying to have my keystore and truststore configured through `application.properties`.

When I add the following settings, I can get the keystore to work, but not the truststore.

```
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:foo.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-password=password
server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:foo.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=password
```

However, if I add the truststore through gradle:

```
bootRun {
    jvmArgs = [ "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=c://foo.jks", "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password"]
}
```

it works just fine.

Has anyone used the `application.properties` for trust stores?

Comment: Which embedded container are you using and how have you determined that it doesn't work?

Answer (score 48):

In case if you need to make a REST call you can use the next way.

**This will work for outgoing calls through `RestTemplate`**.

Declare the `RestTemplate` bean like this.

```java
@Configuration
public class SslConfiguration {
    @Value("${http.client.ssl.trust-store}")
    private Resource keyStore;
    @Value("${http.client.ssl.trust-store-password}")
    private String keyStorePassword;

    @Bean
    RestTemplate restTemplate() throws Exception {
        SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
                .loadTrustMaterial(
                        keyStore.getURL(),
                        keyStorePassword.toCharArray()
                ).build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = 
                new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = 
                new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
        return new RestTemplate(factory);
    }
}
```

Where `http.client.ssl.trust-store` and `http.client.ssl.trust-store-password` points to truststore in `JKS` format and the password for the specified truststore.

This will override the `RestTemplate` bean provided with Spring Boot and make it use the trust store you need.

Comment: Is "http.client.ssl.trust-store" the path of keystore?

Comment: Basically it is path to truststore. However it might be the case that you store trusted certificates in the same file where your have your own certificates and private keys. If that's the case you can use keystore there. You can find more details here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6341566/2065796

Comment: `http.client.ssl.trust-store` and `http.client.ssl.trust-store-password` are custom properties, aren't they?

Comment: @riccardo.cardin yes, they are. You can use different names if you want.

Comment: @OleksandrShpota which is the full name of the type `Resource`? Which class have I to import into my class?

Comment: @riccardo.cardin `org.springframework.core.io.Resource`.

Comment: Can I put the trusted CA certification under my project rather than add it into JVM cacerts?

Comment: @ShaohuaHuang who said you need to add it to JVM? Truster store is part of your project's source code.

Comment: @OleksandrShpota Thanks. I am new to Java. The question mentioned that there will be no problem when running with JVM args, which confused me.

Comment: Hi @SashaShpota can u please let me know what would be the ideal way to write junits for the above customized rest template. To perform a positive check

Answer (score 27):

I had the same problem with Spring Boot, Spring Cloud (microservices) and a self-signed SSL certificate. Keystore worked out of the box from application properties, and Truststore didn't.

I ended up keeping both keystore and trustore configuration in application.properties, and adding a separate configuration bean for configuring truststore properties with the System.

```
@Configuration
public class SSLConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @PostConstruct
    private void configureSSL() {
      //set to TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2
      System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.1");

      //load the 'javax.net.ssl.trustStore' and
      //'javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword' from application.properties
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", env.getProperty("server.ssl.trust-store")); 
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",env.getProperty("server.ssl.trust-store-password"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23):

I have the same problem, I'll try to explain it a bit more in detail.

I'm using spring-boot 1.2.2-RELEASE and tried it on both Tomcat and Undertow with the same result.

Defining the trust-store in application.yml like:

```
server:
  ssl:
    trust-store: path-to-truststore...
    trust-store-password: my-secret-password...
```

Doesn't work, while:

```
$ java -Djavax.net.debug=ssl -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path-to-truststore... -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=my-secret-password... -jar build/libs/*.jar
```

works perfectly fine.

The easiest way to see the difference at rutime is to enable ssl-debug in the client. When working (i.e. using -D flags) something like the following is written to the console (during processing of the first request):

```
trustStore is: path-to-truststore...
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is :
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: C=..., ST=..., O=..., OU=..., CN=...
  Issuer:  C=..., ST=..., O=..., OU=..., CN=...
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x4d2
  Valid from Wed Oct 16 17:58:35 CEST 2013 until Tue Oct 11 17:58:35 CEST 2033
```

Without the -D flags I get:

```
trustStore is: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is :
init truststore
adding as trusted cert: ... (one for each CA-cert in the defult truststore)
```

...and when performing a request I get the exception:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Hope it helps to understand the issue better!

Comment: does someone know why the `application.yml` way doesn't work?

Comment: See [Setting up a truststore without a keystore](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6493)

Comment: !!!PLEASE READ!!! VERY IMPORTANT PRECISION: you have to pass the truststore BEFORE the jar, otherwise, Spring context will take over and you'll keep on getting the same error.

Comment: @avi.elkharrat can you please give some more explanation on this?

Comment: See the command line: `$ java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path-to-truststore -jar blabla.jar`, trust store comes before jar. If you pass the jar BEFORE the trust store, it won't work. I guess, Spring has a mechanism to override and lock context.

Comment: what is this jar file, is this the springboot application jar?

Comment: @avi.elkharrat, thank you for pointing this out. I've wasted waaay to many hours because of this fact. And it turns out there's no one else to blame but me; **they point it out in the manual quite clearly**: `java [options] -jar <jarfile> [args...]`. Everything after `-jar <jarfile>` ends up in the app and not in the Java itself...

Answer (score 20):

java properties "javax.net.ssl.trustStore" and "javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword" do not correspond to "server.ssl.trust-store" and "server.ssl.trust-store-password" from Spring boot "application.properties" ("application.yml")

so you can not set  "javax.net.ssl.trustStore" and "javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword" simply by setting "server.ssl.trust-store" and "server.ssl.trust-store-password" in "application.properties" ("application.yml")

an alternative of setting "javax.net.ssl.trustStore" and "javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword" is by Spring boot [Externalized Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties)

below are excerpts of my implementation :

Params class holds the external settings

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("params")
public class Params{

    //default values, can be override by external settings
    public static String trustStorePath = "config/client-truststore.jks";
    public static String trustStorePassword = "wso2carbon";
    public static String keyStorePath = "config/wso2carbon.jks";
    public static String keyStorePassword = "wso2carbon";
    public static String defaultType = "JKS";
    
    public void setTrustStorePath(String trustStorePath){
        Params.trustStorePath = trustStorePath;
    }
           
    public void settrustStorePassword(String trustStorePassword){
        Params.trustStorePassword=trustStorePassword;
    }

    public void setKeyStorePath(String keyStorePath){
        Params.keyStorePath = keyStorePath;
    }
         
    public void setkeyStorePassword(String keyStorePassword){
        Params.keyStorePassword = keyStorePassword;
    }
    
    public void setDefaultType(String defaultType){
        Params.defaultType = defaultType;
    }
```

KeyStoreUtil class undertakes the settings of "javax.net.ssl.trustStore" and "javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword"

```
public class KeyStoreUtil {
    
    public static void setTrustStoreParams() {
        File filePath = new File( Params.trustStorePath);
        String tsp = filePath.getAbsolutePath();
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", tsp);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", Params.trustStorePassword);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", Params.defaultType);

    }

    public static void setKeyStoreParams() {
        File filePath = new File(Params.keyStorePath);
        String ksp = filePath.getAbsolutePath();
        System.setProperty("Security.KeyStore.Location", ksp);
        System.setProperty("Security.KeyStore.Password", Params.keyStorePassword);

    }     
}
```

you get the setters executed within the startup function

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.myapp.profiles")
public class ProfilesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KeyStoreUtil.setKeyStoreParams();
        KeyStoreUtil.setTrustStoreParams();
        SpringApplication.run(ProfilesApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Edited on 2018-10-03**

you may also want to adopt the annotation "PostConstruct" as as an alternative to execute the setters

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.xxx"})
public class GateApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GateApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @PostConstruct
    void postConstruct(){
        setTrustStoreParams();
        setKeyStoreParams();
    }
    
    
    private static void setTrustStoreParams() {
        File filePath = new File( Params.trustStorePath);
        String tsp = filePath.getAbsolutePath();
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", tsp);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", Params.trustStorePassword);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", Params.defaultType);

    }

    private static void setKeyStoreParams() {
        File filePath = new File(Params.keyStorePath);
        String ksp = filePath.getAbsolutePath();
        System.setProperty("Security.KeyStore.Location", ksp);
        System.setProperty("Security.KeyStore.Password", Params.keyStorePassword);

    }
}
```

the application.yml

```
---
 params: 
   trustStorePath: config/client-truststore.jks
   trustStorePassword: wso2carbon
   keyStorePath: config/wso2carbon.jks
   keyStorePassword: wso2carbon
   defaultType: JKS
---
```

finally, within the running environment(deployment server), you create a folder named "config" under the same folder where the jar archive is stored .

within the "config" folder, you store "application.yml", "client-truststore.jks", and "wso2carbon.jks".  done!

**Update on 2018-11-27 about Spring boot 2.x.x**

starting from spring boot 2.x.x, static properties are no longer supported, please [see here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide). I personally do not think it a good move, because complex changes have to be made along the reference chain...

anyway, an implementation excerpt might look like this

the 'Params' class

```
    import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    
    import lombok.Data;
    
    /**
     * Params class represent all config parameters that can 
     * be external set by spring xml file
     */
    
    @Component
    @ConfigurationProperties("params")
    @Data
    public class Params{
    
        //default values, can be override by external settings
        public String trustStorePath = "config/client-truststore.jks";
        public String trustStorePassword = "wso2carbon";
        public String keyStorePath = "config/wso2carbon.jks";
        public String keyStorePassword = "wso2carbon";
        public String defaultType = "JKS";  
}
```

the 'Springboot application class' (with 'PostConstruct')

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.xx.xx"})
public class BillingApplication {
    
    @Autowired
    Params params;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BillingApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @PostConstruct
    void postConstruct() {
        
        // set TrustStoreParams
        File trustStoreFilePath = new File(params.trustStorePath);
        String tsp = trustStoreFilePath.getAbsolutePath();
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", tsp);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", params.trustStorePassword);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", params.defaultType);
        // set KeyStoreParams
        File keyStoreFilePath = new File(params.keyStorePath);
        String ksp = keyStoreFilePath.getAbsolutePath();
        System.setProperty("Security.KeyStore.Location", ksp);
        System.setProperty("Security.KeyStore.Password", params.keyStorePassword);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I was also having the same issue with Spring Boot and embedded Tomcat.

From what I understand these properties only set the Tomcat configuration parameters. According to the Tomcat documentation this is only used for Client authentication (i.e. for two-way SSL) and not for verifying remote certificates:

> truststoreFile - The trust store file to use to validate **client** certificates.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html

In order to configure the trust store for HttpClient it largely depends on the HttpClient implementation you use. For instance for RestTemplate by default Spring Boot uses a SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory based on standard J2SE classes like java.net.HttpURLConnection.

I've come up with a solution based on the Apache HttpClient docs and these posts:
http://vincentdevillers.blogspot.pt/2013/02/configure-best-spring-resttemplate.html
http://literatejava.com/networks/ignore-ssl-certificate-errors-apache-httpclient-4-4/

Basically this allows for a RestTemplate bean that only trusts certificates signed by the root CA in the configured truststore.

```java
@Configuration
public class RestClientConfig {

    // e.g. Add http.client.ssl.trust-store=classpath:ssl/truststore.jks to application.properties
    @Value("${http.client.ssl.trust-store}")
    private Resource trustStore;

    @Value("${http.client.ssl.trust-store-password}")
    private char[] trustStorePassword;

    @Value("${http.client.maxPoolSize}")
    private Integer maxPoolSize;


    @Bean
    public ClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory() {
        return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient());
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpClient httpClient() {

        // Trust own CA and all child certs
        Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = null;
        try {
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts
                    .custom()
                    .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore.getFile(),
                            trustStorePassword)
                    .build();

            // Since only our own certs are trusted, hostname verification is probably safe to bypass
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext,
                    new HostnameVerifier() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean verify(final String hostname,
                                final SSLSession session) {
                            return true;
                        }
            });

            socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                    .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
                    .register("https", sslSocketFactory)
                    .build();           

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //TODO: handle exceptions
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(maxPoolSize);
        // This client is for internal connections so only one route is expected
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(maxPoolSize);
        return HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                .disableCookieManagement()
                .disableAuthCaching()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(httpRequestFactory());
        return restTemplate;
    }    
}
```

And then you can use this custom Rest client whenever you need to, e.g.:

```java
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

restTemplate.getForEntity(...)
```

This assumes your trying to connect to a Rest endpoint, but you can also use the above HttpClient bean for whatever you want.

Comment: I upvoted this because I put together a small piece of code to demonstrate and proove that the `server.ssl.trust-store` is for mutual TLS (has any effect if `server.ssl.client-auth` is set) and not for outgoing connections. The answer can be accepted as an stackoverflow answer. I also want to note here that the documentation is adaquate enough: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Answer (score 5):

Although I am commenting late. But I have used this method to do the job. Here when I am running my spring application I am providing the application yaml file via `-Dspring.config.location=file:/location-to-file/config-server-vault-application.yml` which contains all of my properties

```
config-server-vault-application.yml
***********************************
server:
  port: 8888
  ssl:
    trust-store: /trust-store/config-server-trust-store.jks
    trust-store-password: config-server
    trust-store-type: pkcs12

************************************
Java Code
************************************
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigServerApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    setUpTrustStoreForApplication();
    SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
 }

 private static void setUpTrustStoreForApplication() throws IOException {
    YamlPropertySourceLoader loader = new YamlPropertySourceLoader();
    List<PropertySource<?>> applicationYamlPropertySource = loader.load(
            "config-application-properties", new UrlResource(System.getProperty("spring.config.location")));
    Map<String, Object> source = ((MapPropertySource) applicationYamlPropertySource.get(0)).getSource();
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", source.get("server.ssl.trust-store").toString());
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", source.get("server.ssl.trust-store-password").toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: I had a separate SSLConfig file with an @Configuration annotation. It just didn't work. This is the only answer that got my code to work. Upvoted!!

Answer (score 4):

If you execute your Spring Boot application as a linux service (e.g. init.d script or similar), then you have the following option as well:
Create a file called yourApplication.conf and put it next to your executable war/jar file. It's content should be something similar:

```
JAVA_OPTS="
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path-to-your-trustStore-file
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=yourCrazyPassword
"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here my extended version of [Oleksandr Shpota's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43235569/3890673), including the imports. The package `org.apache.http.*` can be found in [`org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient). I've commented the changes:

```java
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustSelfSignedStrategy;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Value("${http.client.ssl.key-store}")
private Resource keyStore;

@Value("${http.client.ssl.trust-store}")
private Resource trustStore;

// I use the same pw for both keystores:
@Value("${http.client.ssl.trust-store-password}")
private String keyStorePassword;

// wasn't able to provide this as a @Bean...:
private RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
  try {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
        // keystore wasn't within the question's scope, yet it might be handy:
        .loadKeyMaterial(
            keyStore.getFile(),
            keyStorePassword.toCharArray(),
            keyStorePassword.toCharArray())
        .loadTrustMaterial(
            trustStore.getURL(),
            keyStorePassword.toCharArray(),
            // use this for self-signed certificates only:
            new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
        .build();

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        // use NoopHostnameVerifier with caution, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22901289/3890673
        .setSSLSocketFactory(new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, new NoopHostnameVerifier()))
        .build();

    return new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient));
  } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are in Spring, try just add properties for it (use needed properties), and it should work for total JVM

```
javax:
  net:
    ssl:
      key-store-password: ${KEYSTORE_SECRET}
      key-store-type: PKCS12
      trust-store-password: ${TRUSTSTORE_SECRET}
      trust-store-type: PKCS12
```

Answer (score -5):

In a microservice infrastructure (does not fit the problem, I know ;)) you must not use:

```
server:
  ssl:
    trust-store: path-to-truststore...
    trust-store-password: my-secret-password...
```

Instead the ribbon loadbalancer can be configuered:

```
ribbon: 
  TrustStore: keystore.jks
  TrustStorePassword : example
  ReadTimeout: 60000
  IsSecure: true
  MaxAutoRetries: 1
```

Here https://github.com/rajaramkushwaha/https-zuul-proxy-spring-boot-app you can find a working sample. There was also a github discussion about that, but I didn't find it anymore.

Comment: Downvoted. Even in a microservice infrastructure, there are cases when you absolutely *do* need to configure the trust store. for example, if your service hits a downstream HTTPS endpoint which is signed by your organization's internal CA.