# How to configure TestRestTemplate to use a Keystore?

Tags: spring-security, integration-testing, keystore, spring-security-oauth2, openid-connect

My project has a series of integration tests that use `TestRestTemplate` and `MockMvc`.  These had been passing successfully.

I have now added `Spring Boot Starter Security` and `Spring Security OAuth2 Autoconfigure` dependencies to my project.  I have added a custom class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to allow open access (for the moment) to my applicaiton.  Here is the class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) {
        webSecurity
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
    }
}
```

The application also needs to act as an `OAuth2 Resource Server` so I have also annotated my main class with `@EnableResourceServer`.  I provide the path to the trusted key store as run parameters when running the application.  `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<where the cert is stored locally> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<the password>`

The application works fine but now all of the integration tests are failing.  Here is an example of the error common to all the tests that use the `TestRestTemplate`

```
Could not fetch user details: class org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException, I/O error on GET request for <the path to my userinfo URL>: 
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

It seems that the `TestRestTemplate` I am using for my tests needs to be instructed to use the same keystore that the application does.  Is it possible to do this?  How would it work for `MockMvc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may also need to pass -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore= -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=
parameters while running tests.
For running single test pass arguments in configuration and in maven also you can pass these parameters.

Below two links might help

[Specifying trust store information in spring boot application.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27724544/specifying-trust-store-information-in-spring-boot-application-properties)

http://codeboarding.com/tag/testresttemplate/

Answer (score 3):

## Solution for Spring Boot 2

The following answer is aimed at folk developing against Spring Boot 2 and using self-signed certificates for development (proper certificates recommended for production - see https://letsencrypt.org/).

You can create a keystore file containing self-signed certs using the `keytool` command: -

```
keytool -genkey -storetype PKCS12 \
    -alias selfsigned_localhost_sslserver \
    -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 3650 \
    -dname "CN=localhost, OU=Engineering, O=Acme Corp, L=New York, S=New York, C=US" \
    -noprompt -keypass changeit -storepass changeit \
    -keystore keystore-self-signed.p12
```

The `keystore-self-signed.p12` file will contain a self-signed certificate and this file can be moved into the `src/main/resources` folder (or `src/test/resources` if you prefer).

Add the following to your `application.yaml` Spring config to use SSL and point to the keystore: -

```yaml
server:
  port: 443
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: classpath:keystore-self-signed.p12
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    protocol: TLS
    enabled-protocols: TLSv1.2   # Best practice - see https://github.com/ssllabs/research/wiki/SSL-and-TLS-Deployment-Best-Practices
    key-password: changeit
    key-store-password: changeit
```

Let's create a super simple Spring Boot controller endpoint to test: -

```java
@RestController
public class PingController {

    @GetMapping("/ping")
    public ResponseEntity<String> ping() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("pong", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

We can now hit this endpoint with a `curl` command (or Postman) i.e.

```sh
$ curl https://localhost/ping --insecure --silent
pong
```

> Note: if we don't include `--insecure` then `curl` will return `curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate`.

To test a proper Spring Boot integration test to his endpoint using `TestRestTemplate` then we can do the following: -

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class PingControllerTest {

    @Value("${server.ssl.key-store}")
    private Resource keyStore;   // inject keystore specified in config

    @Value("${server.ssl.key-store-password}")
    private String keyStorePassword;  // inject password from config

    @LocalServerPort
    protected int port;   // server port picked randomly at runtime

    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
            .loadTrustMaterial(
                keyStore.getURL(),
                keyStorePassword.toCharArray()
            ).build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
            httpClient);
        RestTemplateBuilder rtb = new RestTemplateBuilder()
            .requestFactory(() -> factory)
            .rootUri("https://localhost:" + port);
        this.restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate(rtb, null, null, HttpClientOption.SSL);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldPing() {
        ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.getForEntity("/ping", String.class);
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, result.getStatusCode());
        assertEquals("pong", result.getBody());
    }


}
```

As you can see the `setup` method creates an instance of the `SSLContext` object which loads (and "trusts") the self-sign certs in the `keystore-self-signed.p12` file (injected via the Spring `Resource` object).

The `SSLContext` class is injected into a `SSLConnectionSocketFactory` object, which in turn is injected into a `HttpClient` object which is then injected into a `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` object.

This factory object is finally injected into a `TestRestTemplate` instance for use in the `shouldPing` integration test.

**NOTE** - I initially lost time with the following code:

```java
...
this.restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate(rgb);
```

... but this returned ...

```java
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://localhost:56976/ping": 
    sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
    sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is 
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
    sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

After debugging through the `TestRestTemplate` I realised that you must use the 4 parameter constructor of `TestRestTemplate` with `HttpClientOption.SSL` i.e.

```java
this.restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate(rtb, null, null, HttpClientOption.SSL);
```

However, if you're using normal `RestTemplate` (e.g. outside of Spring tests) then
the following works: -

```java
...
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(rgb);
```

> NOTE, to improve - create a `@Bean` method which returns a `TestRestTemplate` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, the first link you posted was very useful. This is my working code for a RestTemplate that accepts any cert, if anyone else finds it useful. It's still dependent on valid tokens being provided but that's another story.

```
private RestTemplate buildRestTemplate() throws Exception {
    SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
        .loadTrustMaterial(
            new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()
        ).build();
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory =
        new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory =
        new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    return new RestTemplate(factory);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Tested with JUnit 4, spring-boot-starter-parent=2.3.12.RELEASE**

I had the same problem when using a `TestRestTemplate` to test a Spring Boot backend with SSL enabled.

My JUnit tests based on the `TestRestTemplate` worked fine when the Spring server wasn't using SSL. But as soon as I configured it to use SSL with a self-signed certificate, by setting its property:

```
server.ssl.enabled=true
```

I began receiving the same exception as the OP.

After many attempts, I only managed to get a `RestTemplate` to connect to the SSL-enabled server, but this class doesn't handle the `4xx` and `5xx` server exceptions like the `TestRestTemplate`, which catches and unpacks them, allowing you to make assertions or inspect them with a debugger, so if I wanted my tests that triggered a server exception to pass, I would have had to rewrite them.

If only I could get the `TestRestTemplate` to work with the SSL-enabled server, I could have reused all of my JUnit tests with minimal rewriting.

After some digging and debugging, I discovered that the `TestRestTemplate` injected into the test class has an embedded `RestTemplate` with:

```
errorHandler=TestRestTemplate$NoOpResponseErrorHandler
```

which behaves the way I wanted. But its `requestFactory` doesn't support the SSL connections by default.

Long story short, instead of creating a new `RestTemplate`, I reused the one injected by the framework after giving it the SSL connection capabilities.

Basically you want to:

1. set its `requestFactory` to a SSL-enabled one;
2. capture its `rootURI` replacing  `http:` with `https:` if the server is SSL-enabled, or the other way around if it's not;
3. always use absolute URIs to make the connection with the server.

Here's the code for the base test class:

```java
[...]

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustSelfSignedStrategy;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;


SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class })
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
@Slf4j
public abstract class BaseTest {
    protected HttpHeaders mHttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    // use this to get its RestTemplate with 4xx and 5xx exception handling and rootUri
    @Autowired
    protected TestRestTemplate mAutowiredTestRestTemplate;
    // the RestTemplate one actually used by derived test classes
    protected RestTemplate mRestTemplate = null;
    // the injected rootURI
    protected String mRootUri;
    // inject flag from config
    @Value("${server.ssl.enabled}")
    private boolean mIsServerSslEnabled;

    // @Before is ok because is run when the class is already instantiated
    // but notice that it's run for every test in the class
    @Before
    public void initTest() {
        if (mRestTemplate == null) {
            initRestTemplateAndRootUri();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Init the mRestTemplate using the injected one with added SSL capabilities
     */
    private void initRestTemplateAndRootUri() {
        final String tplRootUri = mAutowiredTestRestTemplate.getRootUri();
        // fix the rootURI schema according to the SSL enabled state
        mRootUri = mIsServerSslEnabled ? tplRootUri.replace("http:", "https:") : tplRootUri.replace("https:", "http:");
        try {
            mRestTemplate = buildSslRestTemplate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // unrecoverable
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return the injected RestTemplate modified with a SSL context accepting self-signed certificates
     * 
     * @throws KeyStoreException
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws KeyManagementException
     */
    private RestTemplate buildSslRestTemplate()
            throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory scsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).build(),
                NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(scsf).build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
        // instead of creating a new RestTemplate, reuse the one embedded in the
        // injected TestRestTemplate, which keeps its 4xx and 5xx exceptions handling
        // capabilities, just change its request factory to a SSL-enabled one
        RestTemplate result = mAutowiredTestRestTemplate.getRestTemplate();
        result.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Helper methods to make an absolute URI from a relative
     */
    protected String makeAbsUri(String relUri) {
        return mRootUri + relUri;
    }

    protected URI makeAbsUri(URI relUri) {
        try {
            return new URI(mRootUri + relUri.toString());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // unrecoverable
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

While the derived test classes should call the modified `mRestTemplate` this way:

```java
public class UserTest extends BaseTest {
    private static final String RELATIVE_URL = "/api/v1/user/";

[...]

    @Test
    public void readOneById_idNotExists_ko_notFound() {
        mHttpHeaders.clear();
        mHttpHeaders.set(MY_AUTH_HEADER_KEY, myJwtAuthHeaderValue);
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(null, mHttpHeaders);
        Long userId = 999L;
        // this request should trigger a 4xx server exception
        // always use the absolute URI returned by the base class helper method
        ResponseEntity<MyCustomResponse<Object>> response = mRestTemplate.exchange(makeAbsUri(RELATIVE_URL + userId), HttpMethod.GET,
                entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<MyCustomResponse<Object>>() {
                });
        // notice that this custom RestTemplate has caught the exception, just like an ordinary TestRestTemplate
        // and so the following code is executed:
        // check response
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, response.getStatusCode());
        assertNotNull(response.getBody());
        // - payload
        Object payload = response.getBody().getPayload();
        assertNull(payload);
        // - error status
        assertEquals(Status.NOT_FOUND, response.getBody().getStatus());
        // - error message
        Object errorsObj = response.getBody().getErrors();
        assertNotNull(errorsObj);
        assertTrue(errorsObj instanceof HashMap);
        HashMap<?, ?> errorMap = (HashMap<?, ?>) errorsObj;
        String msg = (String) errorMap.get("details");
        assertNotNull(msg);
        assertEquals(mMessageSource.getMessage("user.not.found", new Object[] { "#" + userId }, Locale.getDefault()), msg);
    }
```

In conclusion, this solution gave me the best of both worlds: a `RestTemplate` with SSL connection capabilities and the same `4xx` and `5xx` exception handling semantics of a `TestRestTemplate` class.