# Java: SSLHandshake Exception while connecting to a service in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl-certificate, applepay

I am working on Apple Pay POC and in this process, am trying to consume a rest service, but having hard time connecting to that server through Java code.

However, it is the working good with the below curl command.

```
curl -v --cert publicCert.pem:srk --key privateKey.pem -H Content-type:application/json --request POST --data 
{
    "merchantIdentifier": "merchant.com.xxxx.srk-demos",
    "displayName": "poc",
    "initiative": "web",
    "initiativeContext": "srk-demos.xxxx.com"
}
https://apple-pay-gateway-cert.apple.com/paymentservices/startSession
```

All I have got is a `merchant.p12` file from which I have extracted the private key and public certificate in pem format. The private key has a password same as p12 file and it is `srk` in this case.

I am using Spring Boot with `RestTemplate` to consume the service. Imported the `mic.p12` directly to jks.
And, placed the jks into `resources` folder of my spring boot app.

And loaded this jks through code as suggested in the approach by [Sasha Shpota for this relevant StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27724544/specifying-trust-store-information-in-spring-boot-application-properties) but it didn't work either in my case.

Any thoughts or pointers on this is appreciated. I can call the above working `curl` command using `java.lang.Runtime` class, but that's not the efficient java way of doing it I believe.

I am using OpenJDK8

Comment: darn certificates. who knows where the request tries to find a certificate ... there's the documentation how to debug [ssl stuff](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) how you find something useful there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed [this post](https://www.naschenweng.info/2018/02/01/java-mutual-ssl-authentication-2-way-ssl-authentication/) and it worked for me.

Created Identity store that has got the private key + public Certificate and trust store that contains the server certificate.

What did I miss previously?  Tried to load p12 file using the following code snippet

```
try(CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(yourLoadSSLFunction()).build()){
}
```

**which should not be be enclosed in try with resources rather should be used like this**

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(yourLoadSSLFunction()).build()

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
```