# How to validate certificate in java spring without installing in cacert

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-security, ssl-certificate

From my Java application, I want to connect to the remote host and get the response from that host through rest.
I have certificate of that site, so I installed that in `lib\security\cacerts` in my local environment.

Then I used following code to connect:

```
    URL obj = new URL("https://ip/security/sso/?"); 
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
```

It works perfectly locally and I am getting 200 response as expected.

But when I want to deploy this code on Kubernetes environment, that team is saying they can't install this certificate in cacerts (I don't understand much on Kubernetes ) and suggested me to keep certificate in some location and read that `.jks` certificate through Java code and then connect to https site.

I am not sure how to write that code. I tried this way but it did not work:

```
    final String allPassword = "changeit";
    SSLContext sslContext = null;

    try {
         sslContext = SSLContextBuilder.create()
                .loadKeyMaterial(ResourceUtils.getFile("C:\\certificate\\abc.jks"), allPassword.toCharArray(),
                        allPassword.toCharArray())
                .build();

    } catch (KeyManagementException | UnrecoverableKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException
            | CertificateException | IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext).build();
    HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(obj.toString());
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(getMethod);
```

I am getting `ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException`

Do you have any idea how can I validate that certificate through code without installing it in cacert?

Comment: spring-boot, on board, @sandeep?

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43235569/592355) is a "nice" `RestTemplate` approach, but also applicable to `HttpClient` ... 1 eye-catcher: He loads **trust** material, where you load **key** material...

Comment: .... since you(r team says,) cannot copy it into docker:path/to/java/lib/security/cacerts

Comment: Thank you! let me test this code.