# Google Plus Key in Android app: What Key?

Tags: android, google-plus

I'm developing an Android application and I need to retrieve user profile picture. I already use OAuth to get the token as described here: http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html

Any,I'm not able to correctly retrieve user's info. I've tried with this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

But I'm not able to understand what's the KEY: On my google console I have:

- Client ID for web application
- Client ID for Android application
- Key for server applications
- Key for Android applications

Which of them is the correct key? I'm a bit confused. I use the Client ID for web when retrieving the token and to verify it on the backend. I use the Client ID for Android to check on backend side that the issuer is between Authorized Parties. Anyway, when I make a request to:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

I always get a 401,400,or 403 saying:

- "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
- Bad Requeset
- "Invalid Credentials"

and so on.

I've also tried to look at this question with no luck: [How to call https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me at google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989752/how-to-call-https-www-googleapis-com-plus-v1-people-me-at-google)

But if I try to query the Google+ API from the Google Cloud Console I successfully get all the info.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey @edoardotognoni, I've submitted a bug report on this because neither the Android or iOS Key created in the credentials area, actually work for API calls.  If possible, could you star it there so that it might get the proper attention and maybe fixed?  URL: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=1206&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Answer (score 3):

### Preparation

[The Getting Started with G+](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started) page explains how you get the Key.

Follow the "Step 1: Enable the Google+ API" and you'll sort it out.

Here's the Google Developers Console snippet:
[image]

Of course, you have to **enable the Google+ API** in the console:
[image]

This is an example "page" inquiry:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/115657794332822874007?key=my_key
```

And the result:

```
{
 "kind": "plus#person",
 "etag": "\"7zDxHg5s5mqDKJRPJZIoOsdfecE/hQCtSSux92KyaIK9CGzq7XZppYY\"",
 "urls": [
  {
   "value": "http://www.osijek360.com",
   "type": "website",
   "label": "www.osijek360.com"
  },
  {
   "value": "https://plus.google.com/+Osijek360/about",
   "type": "other",
   "label": "OSIJEK360 (page)"
  },
  {
   "value": "https://www.facebook.com/OSIJEK360",
   "type": "other",
   "label": "OSIJEK360 (fan page)"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://www.webonjee.com",
   "type": "other",
   "label": "------------------------------------\u003e www.webonjee.com"
  },
  {
   "value": "https://www.facebook.com/webonjee.osijek",
   "type": "other",
   "label": "Webonjee Osijek (profile)"
  },
  {
   "value": "https://www.facebook.com/WEBONJEE",
   "type": "other",
   "label": "WEBONJEE™ (page)"
  },
  {
   "value": "https://www.twitter.com/WEBONJEE",
   "type": "other",
   "label": "WEBONJEE™ (profile)"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://www.linkedin.com/in/webonjee",
   "type": "other",
   "label": "WEBONJEE™ (profile)"
  }
 ],
 "objectType": "page",
 "id": "115657794332822874007",
 "displayName": "OSIJEK360",
 "tagline": "Osječki web portal sa 3D – 360º virtualnim šetnjama i panoramama",
 ...
}
```

### /me request

Once configured correctly, you also need to provide an `access_token` to be able to use `/me` request, as explained in the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get):

> If using the userId value "me", this method requires authentication
>   using a token that has been granted the OAuth scope
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login or
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me. Read more about OAuth.

Comment: Yes but in this case I'm using GoogleApis, it is not possible to get the info through HttpGet?

Comment: You need an API key for the service to allow returning the data to you.  This is how Google controls who gets access to particular data.

Comment: Ok thank you, now it's clear. Anyway, I've tried to use the Google+ API in Android in addition with GoogleAuthUtil to get the token and it is working. Anyway, if I pase the link on the browser (https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key=xxxxxxxxxxxx)   the result is still 401 invalid credentials. Maybe it is not possible to get it through a Web Browser?

Comment: I've added further details. TL;DR: you need to provide an `access_token`.

Comment: @edoardotognoni did you try the request with the `access_token`?

Comment: Yes I've tried but with no result. Anyway I solved it using Google Apis for Android

Comment: It's not working because I think I'm retrieving the token without using che right scope. For now I'm using: "audience:server:client_id:" + WEB_APP_CLIENT_ID

Comment: @Saran Since the design for console is changes is it possible to update screen shots, ( I can not find my api_key too)