# Android and ASP.NET MVC HTTPS Connection Timeout

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, https

I am trying to connect to a web service that uses a secure connection.  The service is built in asp.net MVC 3 and uses a self signed certificate.

On the device side, I have created the connection following the accepted solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2012497/620197), yet the `HttpDefaultClient execute` method is throwing an IOException saying the operation timed out.

On the server side, I have created the controller action as:

```
// driver for testing incoming requests from mobile devices
[RequireHttps(Order = 1)]
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CollectClientInfo( FormCollection formCollection )
{
    // get form values
    // do stiff with form data

    // build result
    Distionary<string,string> result = new Dictionary<string,striing.();
    result.Add("memberID", clientID );
    result.Add( "statusCode", statusCode.ToString() );
    result.Add("message", message);
    result.Add("total", total.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-CA")));

    return Json(result);
}
```

I can get this to work over HTTP, but the issue is securing the connection.  Is there some set up in in asp.net or MVC (or both) to handle secure connections other than installing a certificate or the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lied in digging into the windows firewall and setting a rule to allow secure connections from the client.  I should have looked at the simplest solution first.