# Android: update https certificate causing SSLPeerUnverifiedException

Tags: android, ssl, https

We have an Android app talking to a https server. It was all working until the architecture team change the https certificate on the server. Now when the user tries to login it will return the following error:

javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate

I am not familiar with SSL but my guess is that the authentication failed because the old certificate on the device doesn't match with new server one. My questions are:

1. If the user uninstall/reinstall the app, would it work?
2. If not then how can we manually remove the https certificate on the device?
3. Can we make change to the code to prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: Look at this question, and you will get some ideas to start with. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012497/accepting-a-certificate-for-https-on-android

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that it's simply being the Android device doesn't support the certificate. Here is a list of valid CA: http://www.setupmobile.se/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/trusted_roots_ICS.txt

After the server team fixed the CA, it's all working now.