# Client android connect using Https

Tags: android, https, key, certificate

I try to connect a Android client to a server (node) using Https .
I have already connect the client using Http,  it works. 
I have a certificat and a key generated by the server.

I don't know how do to establish the connection using Https. I found similar topic but I don't understand where they use certificate .

see ---> http://blog.antoine.li/2010/10/22/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/

[Accepting a certificate for HTTPs on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012497/accepting-a-certificate-for-https-on-android)

Someone to help ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by following this french tutorial.

--> http://www.tutos-android.com/importer-ajouter-certificat-ssl-auto-signe-bouncy-castle-android/comment-page-1#comments

It helps to generate a key.bks and open a https connection with HttpClient .