# How to make https call to server from phone without installing certificate in app

Tags: android, https

I wanna call an API using HTTPS without installing certificate in app but the certificate is installed on server , So please tell me how to make https call without installing certificate from app.

Comment: [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2012497/4596556)

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar I am getting 405 error in when using same e.g.

Comment: 405 is method not allowed. Have you generated `.crt` in client side? [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23697732/4596556)

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar as i have mentioned in my question .crt will be at server side

Comment: Sorry. I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar Hi i am getting this error now , many of examples availble on play store but none of them is working for me.
  "java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99676/discussion-between-madhukar-hebbar-and-shivam-nagpal).