# Android Trust anchor for certification path not found for Self signed certificate using Okhttp

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, okhttp, certificate-pinning, android-network-security-config

My Server is using **Self-Signed certificate**. I am using Okhttp + Retrofit for api calls. I have got crt file and public key [SHA-256] from the server. Following [this](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl#MissingCa) and [this](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#TrustingAdditionalCas) links from Google docs, I have created a network_security_config file in **xml** folder and added my crt file in **raw** folder and added it in manifest file as

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

Here is my network config file as per Google docs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<domain-config>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">2.48.3.66:</domain>
    <pin-set>
        <pin digest="SHA-256">ofJqMSD8j9q3w5myKalxjJO5OklHyBqgkwgHjqcOhds=</pin>
    </pin-set>
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="@raw/ssl_certificate"/>
    </trust-anchors>
</domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

I get following exception when calling an api

```
Response Failure: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:231)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.kt:367)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.kt:325)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:197)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:249)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:108)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:76)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:245)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:96)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.kt:219)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:197)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:502)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

So following are my queries:

1. Is this the right way to implement **Self-Signed certificate** pinning?
   Because google clearly mentions in their docs that "Fortunately, you can teach your application to trust custom CAs by configuring your application's **Network Security Config**, without needing to modify the code inside your application."
2. If network_security_config is correct then how to check if there is any issue with server configurations (crt file + public key)
3. Do i manually need to load crt file and then use keystore + sslfactory to configure ssl pinning as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012497/accepting-https-connections-with-self-signed-certificates)

Note: For now just to run the apis, I am using a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains as follow:

```
try {
            val trustAllCerts:  Array<TrustManager> = arrayOf(object : X509TrustManager {
                override fun checkClientTrusted(chain: Array<out java.security.cert.X509Certificate>?, authType: String?) {

                }

                override fun checkServerTrusted(chain: Array<out java.security.cert.X509Certificate>?, authType: String?) {

                }

                override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<out java.security.cert.X509Certificate>? = arrayOf()
            })

            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            val  sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, SecureRandom())

            // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
            val sslSocketFactory = sslContext.socketFactory
            if (trustAllCerts.isNotEmpty() &&  trustAllCerts.first() is X509TrustManager) {
                builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustAllCerts.first() as X509TrustManager)
                builder.hostnameVerifier { hostname, session -> true }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
        }
```